# How to manipulate back button?

Tags: android, onbackpressed

when I press on the back button, I want it will work like intent to go to some spesific activity and also refresh the page. I found some codes working in this way but couldn't find the one which is doing what I want exactly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So write more precisely what exact do you want?

Comment: Then elaborate what you want exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code..

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {             
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: GoTo NextActivity");
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),NextActivity.class); // Replace the NextActivity.class with the Activity you wish to open..
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Override the onBackPressed method in your activity, Like:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
/** Write your code here that you want to execute on Backpress**/        
}
```

Don't use the `super.onBackPressed()` in onBackPressed because it will be called the parent activity `onBackPressed` method and killed the current activity.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity, you need to use **onBackPressed()**

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //You'll put your code here, in my example below, i check if the user is sure

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    YourActivity.this.finish();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be careful with the Back Navigation on Android.
There are several rules to respect : https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal
https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal